# Dojo populate combo box widget dynamically

Tags: dojo

Could someone please explain to me why this simple straight forward code isnt working,

```
var serviceStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
data: {identifier: "serviceCode",items:[]}
}); 
//jsonObj is a json object that I obtain from the server via AJAX                                       
for(var i = 0; i<jsonObj.length;i++){
serviceStore.newItem({serviceCode: jsonObj[i]});
  }
var serviceFilterSelect = dojo.byId('serviceSelect');
serviceFilterSelect.store = serviceStore;
```

There is no error at all displayed but my combobox with the id "serviceSelect" doesn't display any options, the combo is declared in the html section of my code,

```
<input dojoType = "dijit.form.ComboBox" id="serviceSelect"></input>
```

Any pointers towards the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should use **dijit.byId** to get dojo widget instead of **dojo.byId**.
Also every item in jsonObj should contains field "name". This field will be displayed in combobox. E.g:

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
var storeData = {
    identifier: 'serviceCode',
    items: []
}

var jsonObj = [{
    serviceCode: 'sc1',
    name: 'serviceCode1'
},
{
    serviceCode: 'sc2',
    name: 'serviceCode2'
}]
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {

var serviceStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ data: storeData });

for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    serviceStore.newItem(jsonObj[i]);
}
var serviceFilterSelect = dijit.byId('serviceSelect');
serviceFilterSelect.attr('store', serviceStore);
});
```

And HTML:

```
<select dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="serviceSelect" ></select>
```

It seems that [it works](http://pastehtml.com/view/1ed30mw.html).

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick reply, I seem to be having several issues with dojo. The documentation is really not so consistent, e.g when I use dijit.byId I get the error that the component am looking for is null and when I use dojo.byId I do get the the component but now the error changes to "TypeError: serviceFilterSelect.attr is not a function", which I think means that the attr function/attribute does not exist? is it deprecated or something?

Comment: serviceFilterSelect.attr - it is not deprecated function. "TypeError: serviceFilterSelect.attr is not a function" - this error occurs because you use dojo.byId. dojo.byId returns DOM node and, of course, DOM node didn't has this function. You should use dijit.byId - it returns a JavaScript object that is the instance of the widget and it has ".attr" function.

Comment: You should check the fallowing things: 1.Paths: do all the resources have correct urls and actually load? Try to load dojo from google code: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>. 2. parseOnLoad: By default, the parser is not loaded and doesn't run, so if your declarative widget there won't be instantiated unless you have set dojo.config.parseOnLoad to true.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, am using spring roo which comes with dojo as part of the several tools integrated to it and a quick look at the generated in browser I see  "djconfig="parseOnLoad: false" I think that explains most of the issues I have been having with dojo, thanks a lot for the pointers. Next I will have to figure out how to configure the dojo that comes with spring roo :)

Comment: Actually I came across this, it helped clear a lot of things, http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-103331.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the code you posted, but if you're having trouble getting the DOM nodes, they may not had a chance to get loaded.

You can try wrapping what you have above with a `dojo.ready(function(){  ...  });`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put items in your store? I can't tell from the sample that you posted.

```
var serviceStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
    data: {
        identifier: "serviceCode"
        ,items: [
            {serviceCode:'ec', name:'Ecuador'}
            ,{serviceCode:'eg', name:'Egypt'}
            ,{serviceCode:'sv', name:'El Salvador'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Yah, the store is populated by json data from an Ajax call, looks like the problem is with the dojo parser configuration.

Answer (score -1):

For dojo >= 1.6:

```
dojo.byId('serviceSelect').store=serviceStore;
```

For dojo < 1.6:

```
dojo.byId('serviceSelect').attr("store",serviceStore);
```