# dijit attr returns undefined

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have spent the past five hours or so trying to get this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887110/1304357) to work but had no luck. For some reason I keep getting `undefined` when I do:

```js
serviceFilterSelect.attr('store', serviceStore);
```

`serviceFilterSelect` does not appear to have a `attr` method on it. The version of dojo that I am using is 1.6. Could it be possible that it is deprecated in 1.6? If the answer is yes, are there other ways to achieve it in 1.6?

Comment: Is the return value undefined? is .attr undefined? is serviceFilterSelect undefined? Please clarify.

Comment: yes the return value of `.attr` is undefined

Comment: What exactly is the error text, before i go any further

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Just an fyi, it is deprecated, but it doesn't specifically say that it doesn't exist. it suggests using set instead

Comment: Just tried `serviceFilterSelect.setAttribute('store', serviceStore);` that also did not work. `set` by itself does not seem to exists

Comment: Unfortunately i can't suggest any further than that, other than exploring `console.log(serviceFilterSelect)` i've never used dojo.

Comment: did you read the comments to the answer? *"serviceFilterSelect.attr - it is not deprecated function. "TypeError: serviceFilterSelect.attr is not a function" - this error occurs because you use dojo.byId. dojo.byId returns DOM node and, of course, DOM node didn't has this function. You should use dijit.byId - it returns a JavaScript object that is the instance of the widget and it has ".attr" function"* **how are you defining `serviceFilterSelect`?**

Comment: I read the question very well and indeed I am using dijit not dojo

Comment: have you tried serviceFilterSelect.set('store', serviceStore);

Comment: I just tried to execute the code by myself in Dojo 1.6 and it seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6UB8g/. If you want us to help you will have to provide your code.